# Running a function in background with aiohttp webserver

Tags: python-asyncio, aiohttp

i want to run a function simultaneously in background while the aiohttp server is running

here's the code

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import web


async def generate_clients():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("Background task running...")


async def index(request):
    with open("index.html") as f:
        content = f.read()
    return web.Response(text=content, content_type="text/html")


app = web.Application()

app.router.add_get("/", index)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(generate_clients())

    web.run_app(app)
```

i was expecting generate_clients() would run and start printing every second

but it wasnt running at all

here's the output

```
======== Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080 ========
(Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAg8e.png)

i want it to run in background while aiohttp webserver is running